# Testbed stub for Google App Engine 'search'

Tags: google-app-engine, testbed

I am trying to test Google App Engine's new full text search functionality in Python with the development appserver.

Is there a stub for the [`search`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/) that allows one to test it with the [`testbed`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting) local unit testing?

The following is example code that throws an exception:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from google.appengine.ext import testbed

from google.appengine.api import search

def foo():
    d = search.Document(doc_id='X',
        fields=[search.TextField(name='abc', value='123')])
    s = search.Index(name='one').add(d)

tb = testbed.Testbed()
tb.activate()
# tb.init_search_stub() ## does this exist?

foo()
```

The exception thrown by `foo()` is: `AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "search"`. Has an api proxy been written for search?

Thoughts and comments appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that since SDK 1.8.4 the search stub can be enabled from Testbed:

```
from google.appengine.api import search
from google.appengine.ext import testbed

try:
    tb = testbed.Testbed()
    tb.activate()
    tb.init_search_stub()
    index = search.Index(name='test')
    index.put(search.Document())
finally:
    tb.deactivate()
```

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE** this was valid in 2012. Things changed in 2013: the stub is officially supported. See @siebz0r answer.

It's not in the [list of supported stubs](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/testbed/__init__.py#172) (yet, I assume), but there's a [SearchServiceStub](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/search/simple_search_stub.py#686) in simple_search_stub.py which looks like what you're after.

I haven't tested it myself but you could try do something like this:

```
testbed = testbed.Testbed()
testbed.activate()

stub = SearchServiceStub()
testbed._register_stub(SEARCH_SERVICE_NAME, stub)
```

`SEARCH_SERVICE_NAME` should be `"search"`, and it should also be present in SUPPORTED_SERVICES list, [otherwise testbed will raise an exception](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/testbed/__init__.py#353).

The way you "inject" this new service stub is either modify SDK's testbed/__init__.py or do it from your code. Can't really say which approach is better since it's gonna be a hack in either way, 'till the init_search_stub() will officially appear on the list.

Also, the fact that it's not in the list yet is probably because it's just not ready :) So, use it on your own risk.

Comment: The answer by @siebz0r is the better one for readers of this question, going forward, so I marked it as correct. This answer was great in the interim, though. Cheers.