# Testbed stub for Google app engine prospective search

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have basically the same question as [Testbed stub for Google App Engine 'search'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872009/testbed-stub-for-google-app-engine-search) but for the 'prospective search' service.

I am trying to do some unit testing for my app which uses prospective search, and I'm getting:

```
AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "matcher"
```

I have looked at the [list of supported stubs](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/testbed/__init__.py#172), the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting), and the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?can=2&q=testbed&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log&cells=tiles), but I have found no reference to anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer on [Testbed stub for Google App Engine 'search'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872009/testbed-stub-for-google-app-engine-search) already points in the right direction, once you find the stub for prospective search.

Such stub can be found in `google.appengine.api.prospective_search.prospective_search_stub`

I chose to modify `SUPPORTED_SERVICES` list in my code, so that future updates to the SDK don't break this. Although I agree that any solution is a hack anyways.

So it all ends up like this.

In the test module:

```
from google.appengine.ext import testbed
    #Workaround to avoid prospective search complain until there is a proper
    #testbed stub
from google.appengine.api.prospective_search.prospective_search_stub \
    import ProspectiveSearchStub
PROSPECTIVE_SEARCH_SERVICE_NAME = "matcher"
testbed.SUPPORTED_SERVICES.append(PROSPECTIVE_SEARCH_SERVICE_NAME)
```

And in `def setUp(self):`

```
ps_stub = ProspectiveSearchStub('./ps.txt', None)
self.testbed._register_stub(PROSPECTIVE_SEARCH_SERVICE_NAME, ps_stub)
```